# Trying to get json data with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

i am outputting json data from a php file (example of my output)

```
{"news":[{"title":"title news example1","content":"blabla bla 1","img":"url"},
{"title":"title news example2","content":"blabla bla 2","img":"url2"},
{"title":"title news example3","content":"blabla bla 3","img":"url3"},
{"title":"title news example4","content":"blabla bla 4","img":"url4"}]}
```

how can i show all these data to div #news using jquery getjson or get and using each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will use jQuery's `append()` method to add an `h2` and `p` tag for each article to the `#news` div.  Obviously, you can customize the `$.each` callback as you need.

*Update* the reason for your undefined errors was because the callback for the `each()` method was missing the index of the array as the first parameter. I updated my example appropriately.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){
    $.getJSON('uri/to/file.php', function(data) {
      $.each(data['news'], function(i, article){
        $('#news').append('<h2>' + article['title'] + '</h2><p>' + article['content'] + '</p>');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I get 6 rows of h2 undefined and 6 rows of p undefined :/

Comment: Looks like I forgot the first parameter for the each() callback. I updated the example accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, by puttin the content of title and content in a new var, i dont know why the fist way was not working, but this way work perfectly :)

```
Query(function($){
    $.getJSON('file.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data['news'], function(i,row){
        var titulli = row.title;
        var contenti = row.content;
    $('#news').append('<h2>' + title + '</h2><p>' + content + '</p>');


      });
    });
  });
```